# Recursively following a directory tree

Tags: python

So I'm working with Python and still pretty new at it, and I need to be able to traverse all folders within a directory, so if `/foo` contains `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/foo` I want to list all entries. So far I've created a class that works inside it's own file but when I try to `import` it I get an error stating `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found`.

Function is found in the file `DirTree` so I'm importing it via:

```
from DirTree import DirTrav

DirList = DirTrav(dir).returnList()
```

The code can be found below.

```
import os

class DirTrav:
    DList = []
    dir = ""

    def __init__(self, dirTrav):
        self.dir = dirTrav

    def dirTree(self, start):
        _subFolders = os.listdir(start)
        for f in _subFolders:
            _newFolder = os.path.join(start, f)
            if os.path.isdir( _newFolder):
                self.DList.append(_newFolder)
                self.dirTree(_newFolder)

    def returnList(self):
        self.dirTree(dir)
        return self.DList
```

Comment: What's wrong with `os.walk()`?

Comment: [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) already implements the functionality

Comment: actually nothing is wrong with os.walk I believe, I just didn't realize it was a function. Thanks! Although, I guess I would still like to know what the error is in the code above to avoid repeating it more times, if anyone has solutions.

Comment: Python is looking for a string, you've provided it a function. if it happens when you are importing this into another file, I'd assume the error is in the other file. Very possibly you did something like: `print(function)` when you meant to say `print(function())` to print the results of something. Print in this case might be a file dump, print, any number of things that want a string

Comment: Importing it via

from DirTree import DirTrav

DList = DirTrav(dir).returnList()
for x in DList:

Comment: What is that `dir` in your `DirTrav(dir)`? Also, can you include the whole traceback in your question, rather than just a description of the error, so we can tell exactly where the error occurred?

Comment: Your indentation is off, but i think that's an issue with how you copy/pasted your code. You don't need `dir = ""`, that is shadowed by `self.dir = dirTrav`. `self.dirTree(dir)` should be `self.dirTree(self.dir)`. You're getting your error because `dir` is a built in python function, otherwise you'd get a `NameError`.

Comment: You probably mean to do `self.dirTree(self.dir)` in your return function, you are passing a function back here

Comment: @Lost `self.dirtree(dir)` works, because of that `dir=""`, although it's obviously not a good idea. The problem is `DirTrav(dir)` in the other script.

Comment: fixing self.dirTree(dir) to self.dirTree(self.dir) did in fact fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert I don't think that's correct, he isn't reference A.dir, he's just referencing dir within an instance method. that should be passing a function in where it should be a string path to a directory. if he used self.dir it would be the path provided, if he used A.dir it would be the empty string in the class variable. As it is, he's pass dir() as its known in the function's scope which is the built in python function

Comment: @abarnert which isn't to say (BTW) that this variable usage is the necessarily the source of the error's he's getting since clearly we lack the data to be definitive, but I don't think he's passing what intuitively we'd think he's passing. I just constructed a test class and ended up with the dir() function unless I specified A.dir or self.dir -- and by A I mean his class, I'm just using a dummy class because it's shorter

Comment: @Lost Oh, right, before the OP (or, actually, Martineau) fixed the indentation, that looked like a global, but it's not. OK, so they're _both_ wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.walk()`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk():
    for filename in files:
        # do something with filename (files and will return all files recursively)
        # note f is only filename and not path, use the following (as an example if you wanted to open the file)
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename)) as f:
            for line in f:
                print f
        pass
```

Comment: Yeah I saw above that os.walk() exists, but if the people of SO would be so kind, I'd also like to know exactly why the script is erroring out when importing.

Comment: Understood, but you haven't provided nearly enough information to help debug your example. And it doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel when native functionality does this for you. If this is a homework assignment and you must work with certain constraints, state that or else expect your method to be challenged.

Comment: If your code is identical to what you have posted above you need to indent the class members of DirTrav